# Transparent BSDF renders hair as black in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, shaders, eevee-render-engine, hair

This is a simple question, but why is the hair in this render showing up as black in Cycles? I rendered it in EEVEE and it seemed to work fine. Also, when testing an only-transparent material it worked fine in Cycles.

[image: EEVEE render result is on the left, Cycles is on the right]

[image: My Node Graph]

Comment: What does Cycles look like with the Principled BSDF instead of the Principled Hair Shader?

Comment: @RonJensen I made a comparison render, Principled BSDF seems to be a lot brighter than Principled Hair BSDF but doesn't effect the transparent/black patches. Image link (Principled Hair BSDF on the left, Principled BSDF on the right): https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/454289617731190784/742771728001794098/CYCLES_principledBSDFcomparison.png

Comment: SOLVED! I tried bumping up the transparency bounces. When this did not work, I tried random values & parameters until I bumped up the transmission bounces which did the trick.